# Violation 'click' handler took 239ms - When dialog rendering React Hook Form (large data)

Tags: reactjs, dialog, warnings, react-hook-form, intersection-observer

I am using `<Dialog></Dialog>` Material UI to render the React Hook Form (form Popup).
When the data is small. It is working well. But when my form is bigger, I was starting to receive the warning `[Violation] 'click' handler took 239ms`

The second things is, inside the form, I have 2 Rich text editor. Then the new warning `[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See <URL>` is raised from 2 Rich text editor component.

[image]

I would like to ask is there any way to avoid the warning, or the other way to show the popup form. Can I use `intersection observer` to limit the data rendered?

Any advices are welcomed.